# Using downloaded datastore file locally - GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've downloaded a datastore file from our google application and I would like to use it without using `appcfg.py upload_data`.

I tried gcloud datastore emulator but found nothing. Tried to put

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/home/user/datastorefile.db
```

and it didn't work out. Strangely, the old data couldn't be queried and when I inserted a new thing to the datastore the file actually got bigger and the new inserted row could be seen. My guess is that it's something about indexes.

Comment: Same problem for me, unable to use the file downloaded with the download_data command, with or without using the upload_data command.

Comment: @DevilingMaster You can use the downloaded file by creating a service account (Search in console for Permissions), furnish a json file and then install gcloud.
Now do the following things:
1. gcloud init
2. gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <PATH_TO_JSON_FILE>
3. gcloud auth print-access-token
4. take the printed token and put it in the appcfg.py upload_data command line as a parameter --oauth2_access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>

Now you can use upload_data.